Excel VBA Editor Won't Let Me Debug My Code: F8 (Step Into) / Ctrl + F8 (Run to Cursor) Not Working
On a pretty regular basis, the VBA Editor breaks somehow, so that I can't step into code (either by pressing F8 or clicking on either the 'Step Into' button or the 'Run to Cursor' button in the "Debug" menu) and execution of code doesn't pause on the breakpoints I've set or on errors that occur (this despite having selected the "Break on Unhandled Errors" option under the "Error Trapping" group on the "General" tab of VBA's "Options" dialog box).
To be clear, the 'Step Into' and 'Run to Cursor' do work in that they run the whole procedure without stopping the code on either the next executable line in the case of 'Step Into' or stopping the code at the line where the cursor is currently placed in the case of 'Run to Cursor.'
I know that code is running because "Debug.Print" statements are working and printing messages to the Immediate window.
The only way I'm able to debug again is by completely closing Excel and reopening it.
I've tried closing and reopening the VBA editor, clicking the 'Reset' button but neither of these solutions worked. Other than doing the one thing that does work, which is completely shutting Excel down and reopening it, I haven't the faintest idea how to fix this problem.

Are you able to provide some example code which shows this problem?

And also include from where you are running the code (regular module, class, worksheet, workbook).

Is it one specific VBA Project you have the problem with or all Projects on your device? Which version of Excel? Windows or Mac? Do you have any VBE AddIns installed? Have you tried repairing Office? If Windows, any calls of Windows API functions (or other external code) from your VBA code?

Hey, thanks for responding. I was waiting for it to happen again so I could provide more specific details about the situation, but of course, now I haven't come across this issue again.
If it happens again I'll post more information.

The problem happens randomly, but I don't know it's happened until I try to debug some code and pressing F8 doesn't step into the code. Or I've set a break on a line of code in a procedure and the code doesn't break, it's runs all the way through. So I couldn't tell you if there's a specific procedure that's causing this. However, it's happened across all of my workbooks and add-ins (my own personal own add-in workbooks, not third-party) so it seems to occur independent of any specific procedure. It usually doesn't happen until I've been working in Excel for a little while.

@TimKipp Please answer the other questions asked in the comments. You can provide those answers following an instance when you have the problem. And also, again when the problem recurs, provide the then existing Error Trapping selections.

Regular module, class, worksheet, workbook, take your pick. It can happen with any project and I have Microsoft 365, so the current version of Excel on a Windows computer. Yes, I have VBE add-ins installed and I've repaired Office multiple times. Yes, I believe some projects may make a call or two to Windows API functions, but not very often. When a procedure doesn't run when expected and I suspect this issue, I have a procedure I call from the Immediate window that has a Stop statement in it. If the code doesn't stop, then I know the problem has resurfaced.
